# How to share static html tabs on facebook

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bit of a problem figuring out how to make my static html facebook tab sharable. The send button facebook creates for me is sending the main facebook page, not the tab even though I'm using the id. Someone please help me to figure the out. Ideally, I would like to make a custom share button for this tab, so if someone can help with that that would be great! Here's the html I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=36628155005";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
</head>
<body style="color:#941a1d;font-family:Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="position:relative; left:555px;top:-50px;">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div class="fb-send" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/ISU-Credit-     Union/234631396431?id=234631396431&amp;amp;sk=app_190322544333196"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

Thank you for the help!

P.S: I tried the instructions on the site http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-custom-facebook-share-button-for-your-iframe-tab/ , but I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: Hi Olga - First off, congratulations for attempting to fight the beast of FB with code, it can be a real pain. Although I cannot answer the question directly (hence the comment) - the first problem you have encountered is that FB have radically changed the way their APIs work. Here, you are partly referencing FBml (facebook markup) which was shut down 12 months ago. Also, the instructions link is discussing php which your example does not feature. Good luck in finding the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could define a variable from the tab then add the variable to the link